# How to create a new post from an imported file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have parsed a Netscape Bookmark File with the [Markio Gem](https://github.com/spajus/markio) and i am trying to import the Bookmarks that are in the file into my Model called Bookmark.

When i import the file i do not get any errors. It tells me the Bookmarks have been imported but it is not showing up.

How would i correctly create the Bookmark from the file i parsed using Markio?

My Bookmark fields are title and href which match what Markio says.

**Model**

```
def self.import(file)
    Markio.parse(file.path) do |bookmark|
        Bookmark.create(title: bookmark.title, href: bookmark.href)  
    end 
end
```

**Controller**

```
def import
  Bookmark.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Bookmarks imported."
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_tag import_bookmarks_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

**Bookmark file i am trying to import**

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<DL>
  <p>
    <DT><A HREF="http://www.google.com/">Google</A>
    <DT><A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</A>
  </p>
</DL>
```

**Edit:**
Not really sure what is going on apparently Markio isn't parsing like is says it's supposed to. This is what my rails console says when i import the file. It's not returning an array of bookmarks like it says it supposed too. This is all it does then it redirects to my root_url.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>
"DAAu8486RreHqnFgUbDnh3/LfQcyvQxRLtqVqFAiQHNWgpZvhZgMBki5bY3IFIWwV
/m8aAGQ6FJywqvjuobB7w==", "file"=>#
<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ffe0434af58 @tempfile=#  
<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150608-26033-vs4o71.html>,
@original_filename="bookmarks_6_6_15.html", @content_type="text/html",    
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; 
filename=\"bookmarks_6_6_15.html\"\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n">,   
"commit"=>"Import"}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'it is not showing up'? What does the `rails server` output say? Was the bookmark really saved (`Bookmark.last` in `rails console`)?

Comment: No the bookmark is not being saved but Markio is parsing the file i believe because in the rails server outputs a bunch of parameters for the file. So what i need is take the contents that Markio parsed and create a Bookmark with it.

Comment: It appears that `Markio::parse` returns an array of bookmarks. That's probably why your import action is not saving any bookmarks. https://github.com/spajus/markio#parsing-bookmarks-file

Comment: Yeah that is why but is there a way i can take that array and create a bookmark from it?

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comments, `Markio::parse` returns an array.
You will have to iterate over the elements and create a `Bookmark` for each of them.

```
def self.import(file)
  Markio.parse(file.path).each do |bookmark|
    Bookmark.create(title: bookmark.title, href: bookmark.href)
  end
end
```

Not the `.each` I added in line #2.

Comment: Ok, so i updated my question with what my rails console says when i am importing. Markio isn't returning an array like it is supposed to and i'm not sure why.